# how to get switching iframe in python/selenium to work?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I've been trying to capture data from the following [link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_en__835__835&ei=gfW0XKjNFeXjkgW8g6PYDA&q=huawei%20stores%20italy&oq=huawei%20stores%20italy&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l3.4596.6067..6522...1.0..0.99.530.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263j0i67j0j33i160.QYVpoia0BL4&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=45499827,9211657,4837&tbm=lcl&rldimm=17275164572016510107&lqi=ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw&ved=2ahUKEwiKrMm8g9PhAhXQ4KQKHY9KDc8QvS4wAXoECAoQHQ&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4#rlfi=hd:;si:17275164572016510107,l,ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw;mv:!1m2!1d45.5258666!2d9.274078399999999!2m2!1d45.443338999999995!2d9.1152195;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4):

I'm able to identify several frames:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
CYCLES=2
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opt)
browser.get(pge)
sleep(1)
comment_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Ob2kfd') 
sleep(1)
comment_button[0].click() 
sleep(1)
html = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
frames = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

this finds the frames:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", element="0.46172414237768167- 
3")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", element="0.46172414237768167- 
4")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
 (session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", 
 element="0.46172414237768167-5")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
 (session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", 
 element="0.46172414237768167-6")>,
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
 (session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", 
 element="0.46172414237768167-7")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
 (session="bbe62090fb83ba8774d855278b17b007", 
 element="0.46172414237768167-8")>]
```

Now the part that does not work... I'm unable to switch to the frame that has the reviews, I've tried many approaches:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))))

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))))

browser.switch_to.default_content()

browser.switch_to.parent_frame()

browser.switch_to.frame(frames[0])

browser.switch_to.frame(frames[1])

#etc
```

I also tried to find frame IDs using browser, but I'm new to this:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("gci_91f30755d6a6b787dcc2a4062e6e9824.js")
```

I'm wanting to basically scroll down the reviews, but I'm stuck in the wrong frame it seems:

```
sleep(2)
for i in range(CYCLES):
    html.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
```

but nothing works?

Please note it's not a duplicate, I appreciate that there are a few other posts with similar problems but I've really tried every approach mentioned and nothing seems to work! If someone can help it would really be much appreciated. If you can maybe try from the page link it does not seem to work.

Comment: You have mentioned about _unable to switch to the frame that has the reviews_. Are you trying to scrape the review texts e.g **"Great service, in English too!"**, **"Very good experience, personal are super professional and kind."**, etc?

Comment: yes, i'm wanting to scrape every comment

Comment: Update the question what exactly you mean by _...every commments..._

Comment: i cant seem to be able to edit the question unfortunately...

Comment: if I can be shown how to get the scrolling to happen in the right frame as per my question then i will be able to capture the comments.. my problem is not being able to switch frame

Comment: You still havn't told us which/how many comments you mean by _...every commments..._ else your question looks **Too Broad**

Comment: all 127 comments on this page, but my question is not about how to scrape the comments but switch to the correct iframe that contains the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element is not inside any `iframe`.Try use `webdriverwait` and css selector.Here I tried with chrome and works fine.Printing me the text `127 Google reviews` is that you are looking after.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_en__835__835&ei=gfW0XKjNFeXjkgW8g6PYDA&q=huawei%20stores%20italy&oq=huawei+stores+italy&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l3.4596.6067..6522...1.0..0.99.530.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263j0i67j0j33i160.QYVpoia0BL4&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=45499827,9211657,4837&tbm=lcl&rldimm=17275164572016510107&lqi=ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw&ved=2ahUKEwiKrMm8g9PhAhXQ4KQKHY9KDc8QvS4wAXoECAoQHQ&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4#rlfi=hd:;si:17275164572016510107,l,ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw;mv:!1m2!1d45.5258666!2d9.274078399999999!2m2!1d45.443338999999995!2d9.1152195;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span.fl span a span')))
print(element.text)

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.Jtu6Td span')))

for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

First print will print

```
127 Google reviews
```

Second loop will print 3 review comments to see more comments you have to click on `More Google review` .I think that part you will do that.

```
Very good experience, personal are super professional and kind. I became now huawei client :)
The team is  really kind and extremely prepared
Good store everything you want from Huawei.
```

**EDITED:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_en__835__835&ei=gfW0XKjNFeXjkgW8g6PYDA&q=huawei%20stores%20italy&oq=huawei+stores+italy&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l3.4596.6067..6522...1.0..0.99.530.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263j0i67j0j33i160.QYVpoia0BL4&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=45499827,9211657,4837&tbm=lcl&rldimm=17275164572016510107&lqi=ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw&ved=2ahUKEwiKrMm8g9PhAhXQ4KQKHY9KDc8QvS4wAXoECAoQHQ&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4#rlfi=hd:;si:17275164572016510107,l,ChNodWF3ZWkgc3RvcmVzIGl0YWx5IgOIAQFaDwoNaHVhd2VpIHN0b3Jlcw;mv:!1m2!1d45.5258666!2d9.274078399999999!2m2!1d45.443338999999995!2d9.1152195;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:4")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span.fl span a span')))
print(element.text)
no_of_review=int(element.text.split()[0])
print(no_of_review)

elemore=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="More Google reviews"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elemore)

all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))

while len(all_reviews) < no_of_review:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until_not(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class$="activityIndicator"]')))
    all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gws-localreviews__google-review')

reviews = []
for review in all_reviews:
    try:
         full_text_element = review.find_element_by_css_selector('span.review-full-text')
         reviews.append(full_text_element)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        full_text_element = review.find_element_by_css_selector('span[class^="r-"]')
        reviews.append(full_text_element.get_attribute('textContent'))

print(reviews)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I try to click on the button but it does not work: 
    comment_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('xwP61c')  
    comment_button[0].click() but nothing happens

Comment: try follwoing code to click on the more button. `elemore=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="More Google reviews"]')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elemore)`